# How do I password protect a .tgz file with tar in Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, tar, archiving, password-protection

I'm using the Unix tar command as follows to tar up a directory and its files:

```
tar cvzf fileToTar.tgz directoryToTar
```

Is there a way to password protect the .tgz file?  I've created password-protected ZIP files on Windows so I would assume Unix has the same capability. Any ideas?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use [`crypt`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-openbsd-unix-encrypting-files-easily/) or [`gpg`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-with-a-password.html) on the file.

Simple examples:

`cat filename | crypt > filename.crypt`

`gpg -c –o filename.gpg filename`

Comment: this makes no sense, where is the password?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Most password-accepting tools prompt the user for it from the terminal rather than a command line argument, as to prevent the password showing up in history.

Comment: `crypt` should not be used since it is considered too cryptographically weak by modern standards, which is also why it isn't included with most Linux distros.

Answer (score 55):

You can use command:

```
zip -P password file.zip file
```

Or better:

```
zip -e file.zip file

man zip
```

Comment: Does zip know enough to scrub the password section of the command line the moment it's run so it doesn't show up (or only shows up for millicsonds) in a ps?  That's human readable.

Comment: No. My zip manpage has a warning to this effect: "THIS IS INSECURE!  Many multi-user operating systems provide ways for any user to see the current command line of any other user; even on stand-alone systems there is always the threat of over-the-shoulder peeking."

Comment: The `-e` option should work. It says `Encrypt the contents of the zip archive using a password which is entered on the terminal in response to a prompt (this will not be echoed; if standard error is not a tty, zip will exit with an error). The password prompt is repeated to save the user from typing errors.`

Answer (score 26):

You can use [gpg](https://www.gnupg.org/) (=GnuPG):

```
gpg -o fileToTar.tgz.gpg --symmetric fileToTar.tgz
```

This will prompt you for a passphrase.

To decrypt the file later on, just do a:

```
gpg fileToTar.tgz.gpg
```

This will prompt you, again, for the passphrase.

Comment: Note: `-c` is short for `--symmetric`, i.e., use the default symmetric cipher, which means that the same passphrase is used for both encryption and decryption. (As opposed to asymmetric, which involves public keys and private keys.)

Answer (score 19):

Neither the `tar` format nor the `gz` format has built-in support for password-protecting files.

The Windows `zip` format combines several different piece of functionality: compression (e.g. gzip), archiving multiple files into one (e.g. tar), encryption (e.g. gnupg), and probably others.  Unix tends to have individual tools, each of which does one thing well, and lets you combine them.

The Unix equivalent of a password-protected `.zip` file would probably be called something like `foo.tar.gz.gpg` or `foo.tgz.gpg`.

And there are open-source `zip` and `unzip` tools for Unix, though they may not provide all the capabilities of the Windows versions (I'm fairly sure the newer `.zipx` format isn't supported).

Answer (score 9):

You can use [ccrypt](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/).

Things can be encrypted by a pipe:

```
tar cvvjf - /path/to/files | ccrypt > backup.tar.bz2.cpt
```

Or in place:

```
ccrypt backup.tar.bz2
```

For automating, you can save a passkey into a file and use this passkey to encrypt:

```
ccrypt -k ~/.passkey backup.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 5):

To zip a file with password run the following command:

`zip -er name.zip folder/`

It will show a prompt to enter a hidden password.

---

To unzip the file, run:

`unzip name.zip`

And enter the password you added before.

Comment: Works on macOS ventura terminal. Thanks