# How to mount a encrypted tar file in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, encryption, mount, tar

Let us imagine I have encrypted my `tar` file with `gpg` as we can see [here](https://superuser.com/a/370390) but I want to mount that with `archivemount` (e.g.: [answer](https://superuser.com/a/631798)) without holding the unencrypted file on disk. Is it possible?

If not, Is there some way to create a encrypted disk image as a file to mount like we can see [on EncryptedFilesystems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystems)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `archivemount` can’t do that. It doesn’t support GPG and neither does it support external filters/helpers.

LUKS works perfectly fine with file containers, using `losetup` and loop devices:

```
truncate -s 1G container.img
losetup -f # Use output in next commands
losetup /dev/loopX container.img
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/loopX
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loopX mycontainer # ...where “mycontainer” is a free name in /dev/mapper/
```

Then proceed to create a filesystem and whatnot. When you’ve finished using the container, close it:

```
cryptsetup luksClose /dev/mapper/mycontainer
```

And remove the loop device mapping.

```
losetup -d /dev/loopX
```

Comment: It took me a time to format, It's better to use `luksformat -t ext4 /dev/loopX` instead of `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/loopX`.

Comment: This solution has a major drawback: It requires one to be able to get superuser privileges.